# How to detect empty sim tray insertion in android

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, android-jetpack, telephonymanager, phone-state-listener

How to detect empty sim tray insertion in android

Not able to detect empty sim tray insertion using sin state change broadcast receiver.
How to detect empty sim tray insertion in android

Not able to detect empty sim tray insertion using sin state change broadcast receiver
How to detect empty sim tray insertion in android

Not able to detect empty sim tray insertion using sin state change broadcast receiver.

Comment: Detecting an empty sim tray would require an extra sensor which to my knowledge no phone has. Only if a sim card connects to the sim card reader this can be detected.